# Shell one-liner: How to get the command executed before "&&"?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh, one-liner

I'd like to do the thing below:

1. execute a command, *commandA*
2. if *commandA* was executed successfully, get *commandA* as a string
3. notify that *commandA* was executed successfully

To achieve step 2, what commands should be used?

```sh
commandA && lastcommand=<some skillful commands> && echo '$lastcommand was executed successfully!'
```

Comment: Which shell, bash, sh, or zsh?

Comment: @haltack : What does it mean to _get a command as a string_? How do you defined "successful"? If you mean the usual conventiion of a non-zero exit code, please say so explicitly in your question.

Comment: @haltack : What's wrong with simply writing `commandA && echo commandA successful`?

Answer (score 2):

`bash` doesn't have anything that does this automatically.

Instead of trying to get the command, put it into a variable and execute that variable.

```
lastcommand=(commandA arg1 arg2 arg3) && "${lastcommand[@]}" && echo "${lastcommand[@]} was executed successfully"
```